# Crawling Tweets with Tweepy 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler, tweepy

this question was asked multiple times, but i couldn´t find a solution for my application. I´m trying to crawl tweets based on the status_id in a csv file, which is working fine. The only problem I have is, a few hundred tweets cannot be accessed due to the 403 Forbidden Error. Am I doing anything wrong, or are those really deleted tweets? Already tested, if I could access the tweets via browser, but that´s also not the case (as it should be).

my code:

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = "xxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxx"
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

import csv
f=open('test.csv')
for row in csv.reader(f):
    if row[1] == 'status_id':
        continue
    try:
        tweet = api.get_status(row[1])
        print(tweet)
    except (tweepy.Forbidden, tweepy.NotFound):
        print("403 Forbidden")
        pass
    except tweepy.NotFound:
        print("404 NotFound")
        pass
```

It´s nothing special, I just wanted to see, if I might have done something wrong, hence why I don´t have access to some tweets.
thanks for helping me and sorry for the crappy code :D

Comment: If you’re getting 403 from the API and the Tweet is also inaccessible in the browser, it would be deleted, or from a protected account that limits access to their Tweets.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to be sure :)

Comment: "this question was asked multiple times, but i couldn´t find a solution for my application" What happened when you read the answers? Why exactly did they not solve the problem for you?